# Django REST Framework - как заполнить шаблон данными без использования Django моделей?

Tags: python, django, angularjs, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

Как заполнить шаблон без моделей?
Использую `Django REST`, `python 3.4`, `Angular JS`.

Предположим, есть 4 страницы в виде шаблонов: `main.html, page1.html, page2.html, page3.html`.

На странице `main` отображается список, который получается из запроса к базе данных. При выборе какого-либо пункта необходимо осуществлять переход на страницу `page1`, и на ней отображать список, полученный также из результатов выполнения запроса к базе данных (база данных не Django), но уже с учетом выбранного на странице main пункта, т.е. передать несколько параметров в `REST`, заполнить шаблон `page1.html` результатами выполнения запроса и отобразить итоговую страницу.
Далее при выборе пункта осуществлять аналогично переход на страницу `page2`, с нее на `page3` и т.д.

Просто делать у пунктов ссылки вида 
`/page1/type=sometype&id=1` на странице `main`, 
на page1 - `/page2/type=secondtype&id=6` и т.д? Какого типа лучше использовать класс для обработки запросов - `APIView`? 
Пытаюсь использовать `APIView`, перехожу по ссылке вида `/page1?id=1`
Вот пример без `type` параметра, только с `id`:

```
class SomeAPI(APIView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if (request.GET.get('id',None)):
             ...
             # result = получаю из базы данных набор записей на основе id
            return Response({'res':result}, template_name="page1.html")
```

в urls.py: `url(r'^page1'), SomeAPI.as_view()`

В шаблоне  page1.html

```
...
<tr ng-repeat="item in res">
{{item}}
...
```

Записи возвращаются верно (т.е. с получением данных из БД проблем нет), но отображаются не в шаблоне `page1.html`, а на странице стандартного шаблона `REST API` в виде `JSON-структуры`.

```
{
    "res": [
        {
            "item": "1"
        },
        {
            "item": "2"
        },
        {
            "item": "3"
        },
        {
            "item": "4"
        }
    ]
}
```

По сути мне нужно объединить функционал `TemplateView` + `APIView`. Можно было бы аналогично, как на странице main, из контроллера `AngularJS` запрашивать у `APIView JSON` результат методом `GET`, и заполнять `template`. Но для `page1, page2, page3` нужно использовать `id`. Передать запросом `GET` его не проблема, и сформировать ответ в `APIView` тоже, но как передать в контроллер для страницы `page1` этот `id` со страницы `main`, например? И как заполнить на основе JSON-ответа шаблон?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы отправить словарь в шаблон, нужно использовать `TemplateHTMLRenderer` в параметре `renderer_classes`,а сам шаблон добавляется в параметр `template_name`

```
from rest_framework.renderers import TemplateHTMLRenderer
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView


class SomeAPI(APIView):
    renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
    template_name = 'page1.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ... 
        return Response({'res':result})
```

[Документация по работе с шаблонами](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/html-and-forms/)

Вообще лучше разделить бекенд и фронтенд, роутинг настроить в Angular, а REST использовать только для отправки данных.

Comment: спасибо. По поводу роутинга в `Angular` - какого вида тогда будет `urls.py` в `REST`? предположим, я переношу `/main` (кстати, главную в данном случае в корне можно только через `htaccess` настроить?), `/page1` и т.д. в ангуляр, в `REST urls.py` оставляю `url` для `api` для выполнения запросов к бд и получения набора записей, верно?

Comment: Да, разделите фронтенд и бекенд. Бекенд у вас будет только для CRUD с урлами типа `api/pages/` `api/pages/page_id..` , как вы описали. К ним уже обращаетесь из ангуляра, в зависимости от страницы. Пройдите туториал на сайте с документацией к REST, станет понятней. Вот еще неплохая серия туториалов https://godjango.com/41-start-your-api-django-rest-framework-part-1/

Comment: по поводу ангуляра, я правильно понял идею? `app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/main"); 
  $stateProvider
    .state('main', {
      url: "/main",
      templateUrl: "main.html", 
      controller: function($scope){
          $http.get('/someapi/info?type=main').success(function(answer) {
              $scope.params = ... 
    })`

Comment: и для второй страницы, где должен быть параметр `.state('page1', {
      url: "/page1",
      templateUrl: "page1.html",
      controller: function($scope){
          $http.get('/someapi/info?type=page1&id='+$scope.id).success(function(answer) {
              $scope.params = ...`

Comment: @Emm тяжеловато так в коде разбираться. Ну что то типа того, по роутингу есть много информацию, его можно по разному реализовывать. Пройдите на codecacademy туториал по ангуляру, там аналогичную задачу предлагают решить в самом конце, брать json с rest сервиса.